# How to remove empty line after 'description' when 'list' is part of the tabular environment within the table's cell

Tags: lists, longtable

A table is created with \usepackage{longtable}. All the cells are simple cells with the exception of the last cell in each row. This cell contains another tabular environment. It contains few lines of text and a list. No matter what I do, I can not get rid of the empty line after the list (see 'second row'). But, there is one exception. If I put a line of text after the list, I do not get empty line. Please, see 'first row'.

QUESTION:
What is the magic command which will remove the empty line after the 'list' ?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}lcccl@{}}
  \caption{INPUT ports definition.} \label{tab:signal_definition_input} \\
  \hline
  \textbf{COL 1} & \textbf{COL 2} & \textbf{COL 3} 
          & \textbf{COL 4}& \textbf{DESCRIPTION}  \\
  \hline
  \endfirsthead

  \multicolumn{5}{c}%
  {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\    
  \hline
  \textbf{COL 1} & \textbf{COL 2} & \textbf{col 3}  
  & \textbf{COL 4}& \textbf{DESCRIPTION}  \\
  \hline
  \endhead

  \hline
  \multicolumn{5}{@{}r@{}}{{Continued\ldots}} \\
  \hline
  \endfoot

  \hline 
  \endlastfoot

  first row  & 1 & IN &  0  & \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}}
                               forces exit from the passthrough mode  \\
                               SOURCE main digital
                               \begin{description}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt]  
                                  \item[0 =]do nothing This is pdfTeX,
                                              Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 
                                  \item[1 =] force some text and more of the 
                                             same text some text and more 
                                                  of the same text
                                                  within the 'list'
                               \end{description}
                               EXTRA line of text after 'list' is needed
                               to prevent empty line                 \\
                               \end{tabular}                         \\ 
  \hline %-----------------------------------------------  
  second row & 1 & IN &  0  & \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}}
                               forces exit from the passthrough mode  \\
                               SOURCE main digital
                               \begin{description}[noitemsep,topsep=2pt]  
                                  \item[0 =]do nothing This is pdfTeX,
                                            Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17  
                                  \item[1 =] force some text and more of the 
                                             same text some text and more 
                                             of the same text
                                             within the 'list' 
                              \end{description}
                              \end{tabular}                   \\
  \hline %------------------------------------------------
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: list within tabular environment within cell]

Comment: *Ad hoc* (and temporary) workaround: try adding `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` after `\end{description}`.

Comment: yes...  this is the magic command   .... it did the trick  TNX++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to do hanging indentation.  Note that `\baselineskip` does not apply to the first or last line of a `\parbox`, so I like to start and end with a `\strut`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\desc}[2]% %1 = label, #2 = description
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{#1\hspace{\itemsep}}%
  \usebox0\parbox[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\wd0}{\strut #2\strut}%
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}lcccl@{}}
  \caption{INPUT ports definition.} \label{tab:signal_definition_input} \\
  \hline
  \textbf{COL 1} & \textbf{COL 2} & \textbf{COL 3} 
          & \textbf{COL 4}& \textbf{DESCRIPTION}  \\
  \hline
  \endfirsthead

  \multicolumn{5}{c}%
  {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\    
  \hline
  \textbf{COL 1} & \textbf{COL 2} & \textbf{col 3}  
  & \textbf{COL 4}& \textbf{DESCRIPTION}  \\
  \hline
  \endhead

  \hline
  \multicolumn{5}{@{}r@{}}{{Continued\ldots}} \\
  \hline
  \endfoot

  \hline 
  \endlastfoot

  first row  & 1 & IN &  0  & \parbox{8cm}{\strut
                               forces exit from the passthrough mode  \\
                               SOURCE main digital\\
                               \desc{0 =}{do nothing This is pdfTeX,
                                              Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17}\\
                               \desc{1 =}{force some text and more of the 
                                             same text some text and more 
                                                  of the same text
                                                  within the 'list'}%
                               \strut}\\ 
  \hline %-----------------------------------------------  
  second row & 1 & IN &  0  & \parbox{8cm}{\strut
                               forces exit from the passthrough mode  \\
                               SOURCE main digital\\
                               \desc{0 =}{do nothing This is pdfTeX,
                                            Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17}\\
                               \desc{1 =}{force some text and more of the 
                                             same text some text and more 
                                             of the same text
                                             within the 'list'}%
                              \strut}\\
  \hline %------------------------------------------------
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: As presented, the solution works. What is puzzling to me is the `%` after the `within the 'list'}%`.  I thought that `%` is the delimiter where the comment starts ...  so ... it should be irrelevant if it is there or not. But, If I remove it or just move it one character to the right like `within the 'list'} %`, the empty line after the last text line appears. Is there any explanation why the `%` has an impact on rendering ?

Comment: Almost every line which ends with } will add a space.  Putting % immediately after } prevents this.

Answer (score 0):

just add to te last item line this command :  `\vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}`
**Edit** : add it before the  \end{description} like that :

```
                      \begin{description}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt]  
                          \item[0 =]do 
                          \item[1 =]   within the 'list''\vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}
                       \end{description}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It does not work. I added to the last item line the `\vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}`.  So, the line looks like this `\item[1 =] force some text and more of the 
                                                 same text some text and more 
                                                 of the same text
                                                 within the 'list' \vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}`  The suggestion from @jon (see above) works.

Comment: both work, for my propose you need to put before  the end description like :    within the 'list''\vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}     \end{description}

Comment: I`\item[1 =] force some text and more of the same text some text and more of the same text within the 'list' \vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}` or `\item[1 =] force some text and more of the same text some text and more of the tsame text within the 'list' \vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}`  it does not work `\item[1 =] force some text and more of the ame text some text and more of the same text within the 'list' \vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}` or `\item[1 =] force some text and more of the ttsame text some text and more of the same text within the 'list' \vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}` it does work.

Comment: the difference is in the length of the text. Look for word `same` or `ame` or `tsame` or `ttsame` .  In other words, longer or shorter text works. Suggestion from @jon works in all cases.